# Cut data from array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have array of JSON objects like this:

```
[ { id: 841,
    when: 'date',
    who: 'asd',
    what: 'what',
    key1 : 'a key',
    key2 : 'a key'
    _id: 544034ab914ae3b9270545c1,
    __v: 0 }, 
{ id: 841,
    when: 'date',
    who: 'asd',
    what: 'what',
    key1 : 'a key',
    key2 : 'a key'
    _id: 544034ab914ae3b9270545c1,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I want to cut `key1` and `key2`from that objects and want to see this:

```
[ { id: 841,
    when: 'date',
    who: 'asd',
    what: 'what',
    _id: 544034ab914ae3b9270545c1,
    __v: 0 }, 
{ id: 841,
    when: 'date',
    who: 'asd',
    what: 'what',
    _id: 544034ab914ae3b9270545c1,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

How can I cut that keys and values?

My method is not working. (Pseudo) :

```
var new_array
for i  old_array.length
   delete old_array[i].key1  
   delete old_array[i].key2
new_array.push(old_array[i])
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? This should be fine. But it's worth noting that you shouldn't need to create a new array. Delete edits the object in place, so if you delete the property from the object contained in the array, the original array should reflect those changes immediately

Comment: @Brennan I don't know but it's pushing old version of objects. By the way those are from a mongodb query, if it's matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `underscore.js`

```
var cutted_object =  _.omit(json_object, "key1", "key2" 
                                         "key2", "date",
                                         "id33", "etc");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourArray = yourArray.map(function(current, index, arr){
  delete current.key1;
  delete current.key2;
  return current;
});
```

That should do what you wish ;-)

Hope that helps,
Jan

Comment: More memory intensive than just deleting in place.

Comment: Thats true, thanks for pointing it out, Mike!
You could do "delete arr[index].key1;" and same for key2.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `[ undefined, undefined ]` with both of your methods. What can be caused to this?

Comment: Are you still reassigning the array like yourArray = yourArray.map(..)? It could be that this is the problem, in the memory-friendly version you just do yourArray.map(<in-place-deletion-method>)

Comment: OH NEVERMIND, you need to return current; after deleting the keys in my code above! I'll edit.

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. Now it's not `undefined` but returning original document when debugging `yourArray`. I couldn't understand why.

Comment: @jfornoff When I debug `return delete arr[index].bet_id` I'm getting `[true , true]` but I can't see any difference when deleting keys. I am about to getting daft. What am I missing?

Comment: Uhhh the problem is probably returning delete (...) which returns true if it worked :-D I can literally type my example above into console and it works :(

Answer (score 0):

You pseudo-code is basically what you need, though you can just delete the properties in place:

```
var arr = [...]; // your array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delete arr[i].key1;
    delete arr[i].key2;
}
```

Comment: This method wasn't working and I couldn't find why. Thank you. @Mike Brant

Comment: Lets nitpick a bit, should be var i = 0 ;-)

Comment: ... and array is undefined.

Comment: @Lazy Fixed my dumb variable naming problem :) This should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem using _.omit feature of underscore.js.

Comment: @Lazy You should tag your question with underscore tag and add answer to your own question on the solution you ultimately ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function deleteProps(){
  var a = Array.slice(arguments) || Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var oa = a[0], dp = a.slice(1);
  for(var i=0,l=oa.length; i<l; i++){
    for(var n=0,c=dp.length; n<c; n++){
      delete oa[i][dp[n]];
    }
  }
  return oa;
}
var newObjectsArray = deleteProps(objectsArray, 'key1', 'key2');
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'`. Thanks but there is a problem, it can't splice